# Why toolbar icon in Android Material design is animated?

Tags: android

New toolbar introduced in Android 5 support library has an animated "hamburger" menu icon, which transforms into arrow when opening navigation menu. It made sense, when navigation drawer was being opened below toolbar. Now, by Material design specs, navigation drawer overlays toolbar and status bar, but animation still exists. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because the guy who drew it likes animation?  Not a programming question, completely off topic.  Also unanswerable, unless you're on their design team.

Answer (score 2):

The action bar toggle icon ([class ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) ) is meant to remain animated even if another view slides on top [according to the material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-user-input).

You can however customize the animation by [adding these styles to your XML files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.styleable.html#DrawerArrowToggle).

For example, it might be less distracting to remove the spin animation when a drawer slides on top of the action bar.

Edit your theme.xml

```
<!-- Material Theme from AppCompat library -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- Add this to customize the hamburger/arrow animation -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowToggle.NoSpin</item>
</style>
```

In your style.xml add

```
<style name="DrawerArrowToggle.NoSpin" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
</style>
```